Rudin's RCA 13.4 Sets of Oriented Intervals
Rudin:
Let $\Phi$ be a finite collection of oriented intervals in the plane. For each point $p$, let $m_I(p)\left[m_E(p)\right]$ be the number of members of $\Phi$ that have initial point [end point] $p$. If $m_I(p)=m_E(p)$ for every $p$, we shall say that $\Phi$ is balanced.
If $\Phi$ is balanced (and nonempty), the following construction can be carried out.
Pick $\gamma_1=\left[a_0, a_1\right] \in \Phi$. Assume $k \geq 1$, and assume that distinct members $\gamma_1$, $\ldots, \gamma_k$ of $\Phi$ have been chosen in such a way that $\gamma_i=\left[a_{i-1}, a_i\right]$ for $1 \leq i \leq k$. If $a_k=a_0$, stop. If $a_k \neq a_0$, and if precisely $r$ of the intervals $\gamma_1, \ldots, \gamma_k$ have $a_k$ as end point, then only $r-1$ of them have $a_k$ as initial point; since $\Phi$ is balanced, $\Phi$ contains at least one other interval, say $\gamma_{k+1}$, whose initial point is $a_k$. Since $\Phi$ is finite, we must return to $a_0$ eventually, say at the $n$th step.
Then $\gamma_1, \ldots, \gamma_n$ join (in this order) to form a closed path.
My questions:

How can I deduce that only $r-1$ of them have $a_k$ as initial point? (Does it mean both existence and uniqueness?)
Why do we have to return $a_0$ eventually if $\Phi$ is finite?


For 2: because $\Phi$ is balanced, $a_0$ must be the end point of as many intervals as it’s the initial point of.  Since it’s the initial point of at least one ($\gamma_1$), it must be the end point of at least one… and since $\Phi$ is finite, you must eventually traverse that one, thereby returning to $a_0$.


You can view this as an inductive argument. For any $a_i\neq a_0$, the first time an interval $\gamma_i$ is picked that contains $a_i$, $a_i$ is the end point of $\gamma_i$. To obtain some other interval $\gamma_j$ with endpoint $a_i$, we need to first add an interval with start $a_i$. This increases both the number of intervals with start point $a_i$ and end point $a_i$ by $1$.
There are a finite number of intervals in $\Phi$. Since we are going through one new distinct interval, i.e. member of $\Phi$, at each step, the outlined process terminates after at most $|\Phi|$ steps. If at the last step $\gamma_k = [a_{k-1}, a_k]$ was added, and $a_k\neq a_0$, then by the above and the fact that $\Phi$ is balanced, there exists some other interval $\Phi$ with initial point $a_k$ not yet considered, so the process continues, a contradiction. Thus, $a_k=a_0$.


For 1, your explanation is intuitive. How can we prove it rigorously? I think it is: (1) When r=1, the basic case is clear. (2) Assume that r=m is right, we have precisely m-1 times that it is initial point.(3) When r=m+1, we must have at least m-1+1 times that it is initial point, and it can not be m+1 which would implie a contradiction.
